# How to convert Blob to String and String to Blob in java

Tags: java, jdbc, blob

I'm trying to get string from BLOB datatype by using

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(cloumnName[i]);
byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
String s = new String(bdata);
```

It is working fine but when I'm going to convert `String` to `Blob` and trying to insert into database then nothing inserting into database. I've used below code for converting String to Blob:

```
String value = (s);
byte[] buff = value.getBytes();
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(buff);
```

Can anyone help me about to converting of `Blob` to `String` and `String` to `Blob` in Java?

Comment: Firstly, you need to make sure you use the right term: it's blob, not blog. You'll get a lot further with web searches when you use the right name. Secondly, blobs are for *binary* data, not *text* data. Ideally you shouldn't be using them for text data in the first place, and if you do you should specify an encoding (e.g. UTF-8) when converting the text data to binary data.

Answer (score 10):

try this (a2 is BLOB col)

```
PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("update t1 set a2=? where id=1");
Blob blob = conn.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, str.getBytes());
ps1.setBlob(1, blob);
ps1.executeUpdate();
```

it may work even without BLOB, driver will transform types automatically:

```
   ps1.setBytes(1, str.getBytes);
   ps1.setString(1, str);
```

Besides if you work with text CLOB seems to be a more natural col type

Answer (score 3):

Use this to convert String to Blob. Where connection is the connection to db object.

```
    String strContent = s;
    byte[] byteConent = strContent.getBytes();
    Blob blob = connection.createBlob();//Where connection is the connection to db object. 
    blob.setBytes(1, byteContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting blob to DB?
 You should do:

```
 //imagine u have a a prepared statement like:
 PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)");
 String blobString= "This is the string u want to convert to Blob";
oracle.sql.BLOB myBlob = oracle.sql.BLOB.createTemporary(conn, false,oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
 byte[] buff = blobString.getBytes();
 myBlob.putBytes(1,buff);
 ps.setBlob(1, myBlob);
 ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: First of all, the OP never stipulated that he is using Oracle RDMS. If he isn't, this code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

And here is my solution, that always works for me

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
String temp;
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myBlob.getBinaryStream()));
    while ((temp=bufReader.readLine())!=null) {
        bufappend(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution**:

Retrieve blob column from the database and pass it to the below method.

```
 public static String blobToString(BLOB blob) throws Exception {

        byte[] data = new byte[(int) blob.length()];
        BufferedInputStream instream = null;
        try {
        instream = new BufferedInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream());
        instream.read(data);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
        instream.close();
        }
        
        int chunk = 65536;
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);

         int length = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((length = gis.read(buffer, 0, chunk)) != -1) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        gis.close();
        bis.close();
        bos.close();
        
        String str = bos.toString();
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

To convert Blob to String in Java:

```
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();//Convert into Byte array
String blobString = new String(bytes);//Convert Byte Array into String
```

Comment: you will get the error "The method toByteArray() is undefined for the type Blob" for the first line