# Convert String to blob java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

i have a from which accept image from user. i sent this form to the next jsp page to insert data in database. i take database field format `blog`. i do write get parameter line, now i want to convert it to blob type. how can i do this ?

```
String pic=request.getParameter("pic");
```

i did not want to use prepare statement to insert data in database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Blob to String and String to Blob in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400497/how-to-convert-blob-to-string-and-string-to-blob-in-java)

Comment: this is not a proper answer @prashanth

Comment: FYI, the English first person pronoun is written in capital. Also, in English, there should be no space before a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by getting byte[] content from String

```
byte[] byteData = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8");//Better to specify encoding
Blob blobData = dbConnection.createBlob();
blobData.setBytes(1, byteData);
```

Moreover, you can directly store String to BLOB column.