# how to type cast a string to blob format

Tags: java, blob

this is my blob format

```
String s=SerialBlob@b23d1da
```

I was trying to read this blob format with the help of buffer reader, due to which this blob got converted to string format. Is there any way to typecast the current string to blob format

Comment: `javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@b23d1da` is the actual data, or is that what "something" has "sent" in a "request" instead of **actual** data? because converting the string "javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@b23d1da" to a blob, will result in a blob with the value of "javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@b23d1da" and a mimetype of text/plain

Comment: MB `java` not `javascript`?

Comment: `Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("..."); byte[] bs = blob.getBytes(); String s = new String(bs, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);`. Though I think that is still far from what you want.

Comment: String s= javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@b23d1da this is my string, getting from url  and i want to typecast the above string to blob.

Comment: @JoopEggen actually my data is coming from webservice which is already in the string format. I m not using the database directly im getting this data from webservices due to this i cannot use Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("...");.....

Comment: As the answer mentions, that text is from a toString just showing the Object's hashCode, loosing all content. The web service must serialize the blob, say as Base64.

Comment: is it *your* web service? if not, you are out of luck and should report it to them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your information is correct, you can't solve this issue without modifying your webservice.

javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@b23d1da is what a SerialBlob looks like with a naive default Object.toString implementation. It does not contain the information you need to decode / fetch the Blob.

If you are in control of the web service, you will need to modify it to return the Blob in some serializable format, whether that's base64 encoded etc.

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable reply. Can u suggest me how to retrieve blob data  from the web service in java

Comment: @debo I'd advise creating a second question, asking how to serialize and deserialize SerialBlobs correctly from your web service, including the code that currently performs that serialization.

Editing your current question would change the question, and you already have negative rep.

Comment: Otherwise, try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400497/how-to-convert-blob-to-string-and-string-to-blob-in-java?rq=1

Comment: in javascript how to send the image string data to (webservices) url, as i was trying to send it gives me the following error message: "data is too long"

Comment: You are better off creating a new question for that. It will get more attention.

In addition, if this answer answered *this* question Please upvote and mark as accepted.

Comment: "http://www.abcdefgh.com?userid=121&blob=javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@b23d1da":..... how can i  get this blob data in the next page ............................................................................. @Ryan stack overflow is not allowing me to ask question so only in comments im asking question

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th